# Fat Free Framework [F3] is not replacing @, what i'm missing?

Tags: php, templates, fat-free-framework

I can replace strings this way:

```
<?php echo $f3->get('Hoteles'); ?>
```

But I can't this way:

```
{{ @Hoteles }}
```

The output is {{ @Hoteles }} I feel dumb and frustrated. But cannot discover what i'm missing. ModReWrite is ON. If i solve this, i can work with elaborated templates.

Hope you can give me a hand.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^(tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

**MAMP Pro** config:

[image]

So in **index.php** i have this:

```
<?php
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->config('config.ini');
$f3->route('GET /',
function($f3) {

    //Set Lang Path
    $f3->set('LOCALES','ui/lang/');
    $f3->set('FALLBACK','en');

    //Set Home at the beginning.
    $f3->set('content','home.htm');
    //See Home inside main Layout
    echo View::instance()->render('layout.htm');

    $view = new View;
    echo $view->render('templates/header.htm');
    echo $view->render('templates/footer.htm');

}
);
$f3->run();
```

In **layout.htm** I have this:

```
<body>
    <?php echo $this->render(Base::instance()->get('content')); ?>
</body>
```

In **home.html** I have this:

```
<?php
      $f3=Base::instance();
 ?>


<!--  card -->
      <div class="card border-light mb-3 mr-1">
        <div class="card-header"><?php echo $f3->get('Hoteles'); ?></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $f3->get('GuiayPrecios'); ?></h4>
          <p class="card-text"><?php echo $f3->get('DescubraHoteles'); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
<!--  End card -->
```

Instead of `<?php echo $f3->get('Hoteles'); ?>` I want to use: `{{ @Hoteles }}`
Because the idea is to re-use html components inside the template. For example that CARD can be iterated using `<repeat>`

Comment: Can you share the part of the code which triggers the template rendering?

Comment: @xfra35 i will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

Use either `Preview` or `Template` class instead of `View`.

### Long answer:

Fat-Free Framework offers 3 different templating classes:

#### 1) View

[This class](https://fatfreeframework.com/view) uses plain PHP as a template engine. See:

```php
// controller.php
$f3->data = [
  'name' => 'Fat-Free Framework',
  'tags' => ['PHP','framework','lightweight'],
];
$view = View::instance();
echo $view->render('template.php');
```

```php
<!-- template.php -->
<?= $data['name'] ?> has the following tags:
<ul>
  <? foreach ($data['tags'] as $tag): ?>
    <li><?= $tag ?></li>
  <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<a href="<?= Base::instance()->alias('home') ?>">Return to homepage</a>
```

#### 2) Preview

[This class](https://fatfreeframework.com/preview) uses a language very close to PHP as a template engine, allowing the use of Javascript-like array notations, [filters](https://fatfreeframework.com/preview#filter) and template strings [compilation](https://fatfreeframework.com/preview#resolve).

PHP opening and ending tags are replaced with `{~` and `~}`, and PHP short tags are replaced with `{{` and `}}`:

```php
// controller.php
$f3->data = [
  'name' => 'Fat-Free Framework',
  'tags' => ['PHP','framework','lightweight'],
];
$preview = Preview::instance();
echo $preview->render('template.tpl');
```

```xml
<!-- template.tpl -->
{{ @data.name }} has the following tags:
<ul>
  {~ foreach (@data.tags as @tag): ~}
    <li>{{ @tag }}</li>
  {~ endforeach; ~}
</ul>
<a href="{{ 'home' | alias }}">Return to homepage</a>
```

#### 3) Template

[This class](https://fatfreeframework.com/template) provides an engine for XML-style templates. Since this class extends the [Preview class](https://fatfreeframework.com/preview), it supports Javascript-like array notations, [filters](https://fatfreeframework.com/preview#filter) and template strings [compilation](https://fatfreeframework.com/preview#resolve). Additionally, it supports XML-like directives, which bring new features such as [loops](https://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates#RepeatingSegments), [conditional segments](https://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates#ConditionalSegments) and [subtemplate inclusion](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/views-and-templates#TemplatesWithinTemplates).

E.g:

```php
// controller.php
$f3->data = [
  'name' => 'Fat-Free Framework',
  'tags' => ['PHP','framework','lightweight'],
];
$template = Template::instance();
echo $template->render('template.tpl');
```

```xml
<!-- template.tpl -->
{{ @data.name }} has the following tags:
<ul>
  <repeat group="@data.tags" value="@tag">
    <li>{{ @tag }}</li>
  </repeat>
</ul>
<a href="{{ 'home' | alias }}">Return to homepage</a>
```

#### Rendering method signature

Note that those 3 templating classes use the same signature for the `render()` method:

```
string render ( string $file [, string $mime = 'text/html' [, array $hive = NULL, [ int $ttl = 0 ]]] )
```

This gives you the choice between storing template variables a global or local variables:

**Global template variables:**

```php
$f3->data = [
  'name' => 'Fat-Free Framework',
  'tags' => ['PHP','framework','lightweight'],
];
// NB: at this stage, any other class can access $f3->data
$engine = View/Preview/Template::instance();
echo $engine->render('template.tpl');
```

**Local template variables:**

```php
$data=[
  'name' => 'Fat-Free Framework',
  'tags' => ['PHP','framework','lightweight'],
];
// NB: at this stage, only this part of code knows $data
$engine = View/Preview/Template::instance();
echo $engine->render('template.tpl','text/html',$data);
```

On small projects, that doesn't make much difference, but on bigger projects, I'd recommend setting template variables as local and keeping global variables for data that really needs to be shared among classes/modules.

Comment: Nice answer … as usual. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Rayne :) Glad to help.